# Running an IF, ELSE stement on a vba SQL query

Tags: excel, ms-access, if-statement, vba

I would like to run the IF, ELSE statement below on a SQL query run from a connection between Excel and Access using VBA. Any idea why this won't work?

```
 Dim myValue As String
 myValue = "CS-SS-22"
 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
 cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
 "Data Source=Q:\TOC Contract Screenings\ScreeningLogDatabase.accdb"
 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

 If rs.Open("Select count([ChangeScreeningNumber]) From [ScreeningLogsTEST] Where [ChangeScreeningNumber] = '" & myValue & "'", ActiveConnection:=cn, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic) = 0 Then MsgBox "New"
 Else
 MsgBox "Already exists"
```

Comment: Where did you set the `myValue` variable? You declared it, but as far as I can tell it's just an empty string.

Comment: Editing it now, thank you! Same issue.

Comment: Same error: "Compile error: Expected Function or variable" on the If line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are after, but it could be something like this:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "Select Count([ChangeScreeningNumber]) From [ScreeningLogsTEST] Where [ChangeScreeningNumber] = '" & myValue & "'", ActiveConnection:=cn, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then 
    MsgBox "New"
Else
    MsgBox "Already exists"
End If
```

Comment: I love that idea! I tried and it says it's expecting an = sign on the rs.Open line. I really don't understand why. Any ideas?

Comment: Awesome, that worked! I am noticing that my RecordCount = -1, and not the actual record count though.

Comment: I figured it out! I took away the count and just left ChangeScreeningNumber and then used the rs.RecordCount. Thank you so much!